# raspberry pi apache web hosting not working externally

Tags: raspbian, networking, web-server, port-forwarding

Hi i have been working towards hosting a web page on my raspberry pi with the BT wifi service the problem is that i cannot host my web page externally i tried to do port forwarding but my raspberry pi won't show up please give me a step by step guide working me through the whole process of properly hosting a web page,thanks (:

Comment: If you can see your web page internally, everything on the Raspberry Pi is working.  You will need to figure out how to enable port forwarding on your router.  That's not a Raspberry Pi problem.  If the access point / router is controlled by BT, you probably can't do what you're trying to do.  You'll have to have a router you control

Comment: Can you clarify the internet service you have please?  BT WiFi does not quite sound correct.  When you say you tried port forwarding - what did you do and do you know if the ISP you have allows home web hosting (some don’t)?

Comment: Please write proper sentences with some punctuation. It's hard to read.